# Why is .splice(1, 0, '.') returning an empty array? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```js
let num = 0.0134;

console.log(num.toString().split('').splice(3).splice(1, 0, '.'))
```

The console.log returns an empty array.

I want it to return '1.34'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How would `splice` return a string?

Comment: `console.log(num * 100)`

Comment: And splice returns the characters *removed* from the array. With a delete count of 0 no characters are removed, thus splice returns an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the reference for `Array.prototype.splice` on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place
>
> **Return Value:** An array containing the deleted elements.

At the end of your code, when you do `.splice(1, 0, '.')`, it **deletes 0 elements** so it will return an empty array.

I'm assuming you want to get the previous array with the `'.'` element inserted in the first position. For that you'll want to do:

```js
const arr = num.toString().split('').splice(3);
arr.splice(1, 0, '.');
console.log(arr)
```

And If you want to join it to a string just use `arr.join('')`

---

Anyway, for your use case, you could just use the `*` multiplication operator rather than converting to a string array and attempting to manipulate that.

You can simply do:

```js
let num = 0.0134;
console.log(num * 100);
```